# ViewPager with a ListView fragment - The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-arrayadapter, android-tabs

So I will start off by saying that I have seen several other people post with the exact same error.  However, I am at the stage where I have tried all ten different solutions and am still getting the exact same stack trace and ANR.  I am using the standard Tabs + Swipe template and have not changed a single thing on it with the exception of setting the first page to return the ListView fragment I will show below.

Below is the code for my fragment. `CacheFrament` is simply a super class that extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.  In this case, I have tried both returning the listview only, and its parent, both to no avail.

```
public class RoutesFragment extends CacheFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, container);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{"No Routes Available"}));

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is the layout I'm using for the fragment, I originally had the ListView as the parent, which also didn't work

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/main_list_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, this is the stack trace I keep getting. Note that this is the exact same error I have gotten every single time.

```
07-28 11:54:43.747  15074-15074/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3387)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3258)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3179)
        at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15364)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4824)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15364)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15364)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4824)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2359)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15364)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1974)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1217)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1390)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1110)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  This bug is basically stalling everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, null);
```

You should use null container when inflating the view, else the container is going to be the parent of your inflated view.