# How to get listview from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-view, android-lifecycle

onCreateView can't load listView

```
 mDrawerListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.navigation_list);
```

in this upper code

mDrawerListView is Null Object

this is fragment_navation_drawer.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#cccc"
              android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
              android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
              android:id="@+id/navigation_list"
              android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

if i don't use LinearLayout and just use only ListView

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="#cccc"
                  android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                  android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                  android:id="@+id/navigation_list"
                  android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

like this xml and use

```
mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
```

this code is work

how to call listview from fragment linearlayout?

change code like this

```
mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false).findViewById(R.id.navigation_list);
```

this can call listView but other error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullPointerException in Fragment's onCreateView() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202107/nullpointerexception-in-fragments-oncreateview-method) ... and bazillion others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `mDrawerListView` is a `ListView` in the `View` hierarchy of the `Fragment` (and not the navigation drawer), the cause of the error is that the `View` hierarchy of the `Fragment` has not yet been created.

In the `onCreateView()` of the `Fragment`, replace

```
mDrawerListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.navigation_list);
```

with

```
mDrawerListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.navigation_list);
```

**Further considerations:**

If you make use of a `ListFragment` instead, you can directly get a reference to the `ListView` by calling `getListView()` (after `onCreateView()` returns). You don't even need to inflate a `View` with this approach, just pass the list row layout in the `super()` constructor and call `setListAdapter()`.

**EDIT:**

For the `IllegalStateException` error, the problem is that you are treating a `View` as a child, but that `View` already has a parent. The problem is covered here:

**1.** [**ViewPager with a ListView fragment**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17910599).

**2.** [**Fragments - The specified child already has a parent.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149981/fragments-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview).

Comment: what is "rootView"? and when this rootView created?

Comment: `rootView` is the `View` inflated from the XML layout for the `Fragment` in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: call root view using inflater and success to call listview but other error is occur :( The specified child already has a parent.

Comment: ((ViewGroup)mDrawerListView.getParent()).removeView(mDrawerListView); this code work thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me.

```
ListView listView  = getListView();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                    Log.e("onItemClick", "onItemClick");
                }
            });
```